# phpmailer not send mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send mail by using phpmailer. I googled it and got [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial) which provide me instruction. I have used following code.

```
require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->setFrom('xxx@gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('xyz@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```

In the result, mail is not send. There is no Error. And output is **`Message has been sent.`**

Can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanx..

Comment: PHPMailer sends via the PHP `mail()` function by default, which sends via your local mail server - so you need to check that your mail server is configured correctly.

Comment: chk your spam folder in your mail

Comment: @M Hamza Javed, I checked my spam folder as well sent folder but there is no mail.